# How to find summary from correlation results?

Tags: python, numpy, correlation

I ran correlations between the Metric-1 and Metric-2 for each day of June. I found the result, attached in the image. I want to summarize this data for a non-technical user.

[Correlation Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v88Tm.png)

I want to summarize the results and give a statement to the users. For example: In June, the metrics 1 and 2 were positively correlated and had an average of 0.41.

I am not sure if average is the right way to summarise the correlation results, as it would cancel out some negatives with positives. Any other way I can summarise the result for the entire month of June?

Comment: Plot all the data, it's often the best way to give an idea of both the trend and dispersion. or maybe boxplot? Anyway, the question is offtopic

Comment: Yes averaging correlations might not be good depending on your data. Can't you concatenate series for the whole month and then correlate ?

Comment: See https://doi.org/10.3758/BF03334690 and https://doi.org/10.1080/00221309809595548 about averaging correlations.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on pandas, you can get summary statistics using the `describe()` method.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':[f'{x}-June' for x in range(1,11)], 'Correlation Values':[x/10.1 for x in random.choices(range(0, 10), k=10)]})
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format="%d-%B")
df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.strftime('%B'))['Correlation Values'].mean().sort_values()
```

The second line converts the Date column to datetime so we can extract year/month/days from it. Finally, you can use groupby months to get the average results.